# If $ Av=Bv=\lambda v$, can we conclude that $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A $ and $B$ be $2\times2$ matrices with integer entries. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$ with the same eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$. So we have
$$
Av=Bv=\lambda v.
$$

My question is the following:

Under which restrictions can we conclude that $A=B$ ? Or is it always $A=B$ ? Does it depend on the singularity of $A$ and $B$ ?

In other words, if a vector $v$ is an eigenvector with a non-zero eigenvalue for some matrix $A$, is $A$ unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A$ to be the identity matrix (i.e. 1 on the diagonal zero otherwise). Then clearly every non-zero vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

In this case, would you say that any matrix $B$ with an eigenvalue $1$ is the identity matrix? (The answer is no, see @ Floris' answer).

---

You can't deduce that $A=B$ if they only have one common eigenvalue (unless you have $1\times 1$ matrices). However if you show that $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ have $n$ common eigenvalues then you will be able to show that $A=B$ (up to a change of basis).

Comment: The last statement is not true. Not only eigenvalues should be equal, but also their geometric multiplicities, and even that is not quite enough.

Comment: @Zeekless The last statement is true, but not general. I didn't want to go into all the details. All I said is that if $A$ and $B$ have $n$ common eigenvalues (this of course assumes that the multiplicities are 1 and that there are $n$ different eigenvalues) then $A=B$ up to a change of basis (because you can take them in different order). If an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues then it is similar to a diagonal matrix, the same with $B$ and so $A,B$ are similar (i.e. can get the one from the other by changing basis).

Comment: @amd right, I thought that would be clear from the context. Anyway I added it.

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0\\
   0       & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0\\
    0      & 2\\ \end{bmatrix}$. For both $\begin{bmatrix}
    1       \\
    0      \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.